# In JupyterLab ipywidgets Output widget in context manger shows pyplot figure without explicit calling

Tags: matplotlib, widget, ipython, jupyter-lab

If I run this example in two JupyterLab cells:

Cell[1]:

```
%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

output = widgets.Output()
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

with output:
    print('Print works as expected.')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

Cell[2]:

```
int_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=10, step=1)

def update(change):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(change.new * x))
    # fig.canvas.draw() # This is not needed for update for some reason

int_slider.observe(update, 'value')
widgets.HBox([int_slider, output])
```

The figure is displayed under cell 1 and the slider with the text under cell 2.

**The expected behavior** would be showing everything under cell 2.

If I use "%matplotlib notebook" then the figure disappears from the output of cell 1.
The slider and the text are displayed correctly under cell 2 together with a "Javascript Error: IPython is not defined".

**I also tried** "%matplotlib inline" which shows the figure incorrectly under cell 1 and the figure is not following the slider anymore.

**Question:** How to avoid this unexpected result and make the figure respect the Output widget like the print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

In the first cell call `plt.close()` after plotting the data. This prevents the figure from being displayed right away.

In the second cell create a new Canvas figure and use it to store the original figure. Set this Canvas and call `plt.show()` to display the desired plot. It will still be interactive but will only be shown after the second cell is run.

#### Code

```
############## First Cell ##############

%matplotlib widget
import ipywidgets as widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

output = widgets.Output()
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

with output:
    print('Print works as expected.')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
    plt.close()
```

```
############## Second Cell ##############

int_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=1, min=0, max=10, step=1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
manage = fig2.canvas.manager
manage.canvas.figure = fig
fig.set_canvas(manage.canvas)
plt.show()

def update(change):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(change.new * x))

int_slider.observe(update, 'value')
widgets.HBox([int_slider, output])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Based on this, I was able to find a detailed explanation of what's going on here.  https://copyprogramming.com/howto/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed